# Can't set UITableView to be below navigation bar - gaps occured

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Auto layout is disabled.
On the view I have `UINavigationBar` at the top.
I have added `UITableView` in the XIB file (**grouped**) and set it in the **IB** to be at the top just bellow navigation bar.
But some strange gaps are displayed like on the images bellow.
[image]
[image]
I can't figure how to setup this layout I don't know from where gaps are comming. Any help (I use IOS 7 xcode 5)?

**UPDATE**
When I add your code:
[image]
Then I have tried from xcode again:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The gaps come from the UITableViewStyleGrouped style. The edgedForExtendedLayout won't remove these gaps. If you don't want the gaps then use UITableViewStylePlain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple set height of header 0.00001, if you set 0 it will be use auto value.

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.00000001;
}
```

From Interface Builder

[image: From IB]

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: I've updated answer, add screenshots. I don't know why don't work for you. Set height in XIB don't work. In code works perfectly. And think abount don't use table. Because it not table, it simple 2 labels and 2 text views. Make all simpler as possible...

Comment: I get view like you but button bellow is too far from table even I put it in IB just bellow table, I don't understand what happens?

Answer (score -1):

Set edgesForExtendedLayout of your controller to uirectedgenone